# Comma Use Confusion

Tags: commas

1. She can become enraged, even murderous at times.
2. She can become enraged, even murderous, at times.

Which of these is correct and why?

Comment: The second comma is optional. It's only there to reflect a pause in speech - and while *some* speakers would pause there, others *wouldn't.*

Comment: ... and some would on Mondays.

Comment: Welcome! To help us give you a more meaningful answer, please edit your question to add a bit about why one of them gives you concerns (they are in fact both valid, with slightly different meanings).

Comment: To clarify, the "slightly different meanings" referred to by @AndyBonner above may in fact be simply a matter of opinion (though the meaning probably *doesn't* depend on whether it's Monday or not! :) To my mind, if the comma / pause is ***not*** included, this more strongly implies it's ***more likely*** that she'll become murderous (than if the comma / pause ***is*** present, in which case the possibility of her becoming "murderous" is more explicitly reduced to a ***parenthetical*** mention of a peripherally-relevant extreme case).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That looks like an answer. Please **write an answer.** (Just copying the comment will be fine)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: No problem. At the time of writing that comment, I was intending to closevote for migration to ELL, so posting an Answer didn't seem appropriate. But that was when I was just making that lame crack reflecting Edwin's comment - once I'd mulled over the implications of Andy's reference to different possible meanings, I decided my point was maybe a bit too obscure for ELL.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, the "slightly different meanings" referred to by @AndyBonner in a comment may in fact be simply a matter of opinion (though the meaning probably doesn't depend on whether it's Monday or not! :)

To my mind, if the comma / pause is ***not*** included, this more strongly implies it's more likely that she'll become murderous (than if the comma / pause ***is*** present, in which case the possibility of her becoming "murderous" is more explicitly reduced to a parenthetical mention of a peripherally-relevant extreme case).

This is because we tend to assume that "parenthetical" clauses aren't necessarily very significant (they can after all normally be removed without seriously affecting the meaning of the remaining text).

Comment: And I should expand on my vague hint about "different meanings": We could rearrange the sentence as *At times, she can become enraged, even murderous* (meaning "Sometimes she can become murderously enraged") OR *She can become enraged, even, at times, murderous* (meaning she can become enraged, and sometimes murderous). The distinction is not critical, since we are probably not implying every rage of hers is in fact murderous—but with a different sentence the distinction could become more crucial. To the original question: neither is invalid, but one might alter the intended meaning.

Comment: This is a bit contrived, but how about: *I play chess, and win sometimes* vs *I play chess, and win, sometimes*. The latter leaves open the possibility that "I don't always play chess... but when I do, I WIN."

Comment: Re "we are probably not implying every rage of hers is in fact murderous" - I'd say that interpretation is actually *impossible* because of the word ***even***. Just as with your chess example, where if we include that word as *I play chess, and **even** win, sometimes*, for me at least, that seems to rule out the interpretation ***I always win** [on those relatively rare occasions when I play]*.

Comment: Actually I'd disagree (on technical grounds; I think common sense sorts it out); "even" can be an intensifier: "I was angry—incensed, even." In the OP sentence, as I say, I doubt anyone takes that reading, but semantically it's on the table.

Comment: Okay, point taken. Most English utterances have a potentially *enormous* range of possible meanings, if we're prepared to put enough effort into dreaming up [in]appropriate contrived contexts! :)